# Jquery can't scroll to top of element on div click

Tags: jquery, scroll

I need to scroll to a specific point on the page when an element is clicked. I've tried the following based on other answers found on here, but I can't get it to activate.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#activate_button').click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#second_header").offset().top
      }, 2000);
    });    

});
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? There is no output to the console in chrome.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle? First assumption: did you import jquery library in your page?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gcURs/86/ please check this its working please check your element ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML CODE:

```
<div id="activate_button">
    hi
</div>

<div id="second_header">
    2nd div
</div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
#activate_button{margin-bottom:900px;}
```

JQUERY CODE:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#activate_button').click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#second_header").offset().top
      }, 2000);
    });    

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/00yvp6rz/